# Large background image pan zoom and animate to coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, zooming, pan

I'm looking for a solution to pan and zoom a large background image and when you click on a link in the menu it has to animate to x and y coordinates of that background image. I've tried the smooth zoom pan jquery plugin: http://codecanyon.net/item/smooth-zoom-pan-jquery-image-viewer/511142

Problem with this plugin is that the animation is terrible slow on iPad (Retina). It's already using transform 3d for hardware acceleration. The image is a SVG. I also sliced the SVG in smaller tiles (like Google Maps) and also tried this in PNG format but this didn't make any difference.

The background size on a normal screen is 5300px * 3000px.

Comment: Not sure without an example to test, but you could play with animating the viewBox in SVG. https://code.google.com/p/svgpan/ may also be of interest. Not sure how iPad SVG performance is in general though.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I don't know if it's the best solution but I solved it by putting the whole SVG binary code into my HTML. It works perfectly fine now!